# Page you are looking for not found laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel, routes

I am getting the

> Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.

On Laravel 5.5.  I am sure I'm missing something very small.  But not sure what it is because I'm a laravel learner.  Please see below:

ROUTE

```
 Auth::routes();
Route::get('/curriculum-sections','CurriculumsectionsController@index')->name('curriculum-sections');
Route::resource('/curriculum-sections','CurriculumsectionsController');
```

CONTROLLER

```
public function show(Curriculumsection $curriculumsection)
{
    //
    $curriculum = Curriculum::findOrFail($curriculumsection->id);
    return view('curriculum-sections.show', ['curriculum'=>$curriculum]);
}
```

and I also made sure that the page exists in the views folder.  While troubleshooting I also did `php artisan route:list` and this is what I got[image]

Edit:
I am accessing the error from:

> http://localhost:8000/curriculum-sections/1

Comment: What is the URL you are accessing to have that error?

Comment: @LionelChan Updated the question

Comment: Where is the ID in your URL?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir I updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your route defines `id` for model `Curriculumsection`. You're using model binding, which will automatically query for `Curriculumsection::findOrFail(route_id)` (in your case route_id is 1). And then you're using the same `id` to query model `Curriculum` as well, with `->findOrFail(route_id)`.

So in order for this route to return anything other than 404, you have to have a record of `Curriculumsection` with id 1 and a record of `Curriculum` with id 1 in your database.

I'm not sure how your database is set up, or how these 2 models are related to each other, but definitely not by same `id` (otherwise, why not have all data in the same table).

Something like this would make more sense (binding the `Curriculum` model directly):

```
public function show(Curriculum $curriculum)
{
    return view('curriculum-sections.show', ['curriculum'=>$curriculum]);
}
```

This would bind the `Curriculum` model to the route and automatically fetch the one with passed in `id`.

Or something like this for your use case, but it assumes that you have a working relationship called `curriculum()` on your `Curriculumsection` model:

```
public function show(Curriculumsection $curriculumsection)
{
    $curriculum = $curriculumsection->curriculum;
    return view('curriculum-sections.show', ['curriculum'=>$curriculum]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont think that you need the first get route. You just define the Route::resource(...) and that's it. Laravel handles the different requests.

[See here -> Resource Controllers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/controllers#resource-controllers)